# Best way to group meteor collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor

The `Meteor` project I'm working on right now has multiple collections: *Projects*, *Sensors*, and *Readings*. Looking at it relationally, Users have many *Projects*, *Projects* have many *Sensors*, and *Sensors* have_many *Readings*.

What's the best way to organize this within `Meteor`? Right now I have created three discrete collections, and each item in the *Sensors* and *Readings* collections has a "**parent**" field with a `mongo` _id to relate it to the parent.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it, the alternative being having one all-encompassing collection "*Projects*" that contains all the information about the sensors and readings that belong to it. When adding a new *Sensor* to a project, all you'd need to do is append a newly instantiated *Sensor* object to the *Project.Sensors* array.

What do you think?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the good pattern to solve a problem. Therefore it would be more appropriate on programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your use case. Will your app be more write or read heavy?

The way you've set it up right now is called a normalized fashion. You don't have redundant data and data is related to other data in other collections. (Like a table join in SQL). When you update data, you only have to update the small record it is part of. The downside is when you need to read a lot of data it takes a while longer because of all the different db queries.

The alternative you're suggesting is called denormalization, where you add redundant data to records or group collections into larger collections. This has the advantage that when reading data you don't need that many db look-ups as all the data you need is mostly in one record. On the other hand, writing to the db becomes more complex since you don't need to update one small record but one or more large records.

Either way, both methods are used, it just depends on the use case and how you want your app to perform (more read or more write performance).